# SQL 'with' and 'group by' clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, common-table-expression

Can you please tell me what's wrong in this query?

```
with myFriends as (select objectAuthor,memberId,objectSubject,rating,memberSubjectEq4 from tblRating group by objectAuthor,memberId,objectSubject,rating,memberSubjectEq4)
select authorId,subjectId,(
    (
        select memberSubjectEq4*(sum(rating)+1) from myFriends where myFriends.objectAuthor=AAA.authorId and myFriends.objectSubject=AAA.subjectId
    )

) as XF from tblMC AAA group by authorId,subjectId;
```

When I run it in MS SQL Server 2014, I will receive following error:

> Column 'myFriends.memberSubjectEq4' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

Comment: What aspect of the error do you not understand?  It seems pretty clear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Why I receive the error? I want to find the multiplying of the columns in line 4.

Comment: @Siavash "memberSubjectEq4" is outside your sum function. Restructure either your algebra or your query so it isn't to resolve the error.

Comment: Why did you SUM rating, but not memberSubjectEq4?

Comment: See here for many explanations regarding this error: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql-server]+is+invalid+in+the+select+list

Comment: @GordonLinoff Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @TabAlleman It is a complex query. Table tblEQ4 is a result of about 10 queries. But now I want to have multiplying result of the columns.

Comment: It is unclear what the select is trying to do.  You are starting with a list of IDs with individual `rating` and `memberSubjectEq4` values.  Then you are taking the total of *all* the `rating`s and trying to multiply by `memberSubjectEq4`.  SQL is basically saying "which memberSubjectEq4? I have a bunch of them."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just move your calculation into your CTE and then left join to the CTE to get the XF amount.

```
WITH    myFriends AS 
(   SELECT  objectAuthor,
            objectSubject,
            memberSubjectEq4 * (SUM(rating) + 1) AS XF
    FROM    tblRating
    GROUP BY  objectAuthor,
            objectSubject,
            memberSubjectEq4
)
SELECT  authorId,
        subjectId,
        SUM(myFriends.XF) XF
FROM    tblMC AAA
        LEFT JOIN myFriends ON myFriends.objectAuthor = AAA.authorId
                                AND myFriends.objectSubject = AAA.subjectId
GROUP BY authorId,
        subjectId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you do an Aggregate Function with a column, you must include the rest of them on the Group By

```
with myFriends as (select objectAuthor,memberId,objectSubject,rating,memberSubjectEq4 from tblRating group by objectAuthor,memberId,objectSubject,rating,memberSubjectEq4)
select authorId,subjectId,(
    (
        select memberSubjectEq4*(sum(rating)+1) from myFriends where myFriends.objectAuthor=AAA.authorId and myFriends.objectSubject=AAA.subjectId
        group by memberSubjectEq4
    )

) as XF from tblMC AAA group by authorId,subjectId;
```